# INS-06101 when installing Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

can i get some help.. i dont know what to do. i want to try to install oracle 11g(11.2.0.1) on my vmware (Centos 6.5) but the first time it show error [INS-06101]. i already check my /etc/hosts and my /etc/sysconfig/network there's no something wrong. can you all help me ?

```
login as: root
root@192.168.75.134's password:
Last login: Sat Feb  8 23:35:35 2014 from 192.168.75.1
[root@monkey ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.75.134          monkey.localdomain    monkey
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
[root@monkey ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=monkey.localdomain
NTPSERVERARGS=iburst
[root@monkey ~]#*
```

thanks
Sony

Comment: What is the exactly error message?

Comment: [INS-06101 IP Address of localhost could not be determined]

Comment: Please update your question.

Comment: it said "[INS-06101 IP Address of localhost could not be determined]"

Comment: i already check my hosts and my hostname its all right, but its still return [INS-06101 IP Address of localhost could not be determined].. can you help me ?

Comment: Sorry, I does not know how to fix this, [Google the error message may be helpful](https://www.google.com/search?q=IP+Address+of+localhost+could+not+be+determined&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the difference between:

```
vi /etc/hosts
vi /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Answer (score 0):

old post I know, but for anyone that may need it in the future

add the machine hostname in the /etc/hosts and set it as 127.0.0.1

vi /etc/hosts

add the following line

YOUR_MACHINE_FQDN   127.0.0.1

save and restart the network

/etc/init.d/network restart

launch the installation again